# Issues with COPY when using multistage Dockerfile builds -- no such file or directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to convert my project to use multi-stage builds. However, the final step always fails with an error:

```
Step 11/13 : COPY --from=build /bin/grafana-server /bin/grafana-server
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/xxxx/merged/bin/grafana-server: no such file or directory
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM golang:latest AS build

ENV SRC_DIR=/go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana/
ENV GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1

COPY . $SRC_DIR
WORKDIR $SRC_DIR

# Building of Grafana
RUN \
  npm run build && \
  go run build.go setup && \
  go run build.go build

# Create final stage containing only required artifacts
FROM scratch
COPY --from=build /bin/grafana-server /bin/grafana-server

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["./bin/grafana-server"]
```

The `build.go build` step will output artifacts to `./bin/` -- The error is pretty unhelpful other than telling me the files don't exist where I think they should exist.

My folder structure on my machine is:

```
--| ~/Documents/dev/grafana/src/grafana/grafana
--------| bin
------------| <grafan-server builds to here>

--------| deploy
------------| docker
----------------| Dockerfile
```

From `~/Documents/dev/grafana/src/grafana/grafana` is where I issue: `docker build -t grafana -f deploy/docker/Dockerfile .`

Comment: I think there's a mix-up between relative paths (`./bin/grafana-server`) and absolute paths (`/bin/grafana-server`). So I'd say you should review your Dockerfile w.r.t. the commands `WORKDIR`, `COPY --from=build` and `CMD`.

Answer (score 10):

To follow-up my comment, the path you set with the `WORKDIR` is absolute and should be specified in the same way in the `COPY --from=build` command.

So this could lead to the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest AS build

ENV SRC_DIR=/go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana/
ENV GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1

COPY . $SRC_DIR
WORKDIR $SRC_DIR

# Building of Grafana
RUN \
  npm run build && \
  go run build.go setup && \
  go run build.go build

# Create final stage containing only required artifacts
FROM scratch

ENV SRC_DIR=/go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana/
WORKDIR $SRC_DIR

COPY --from=build ${SRC_DIR}/bin/grafana-server ${SRC_DIR}/bin/grafana-server

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["./bin/grafana-server"]
```

(only partially tested)

Comment: Is it necessary to set `ENV SRC_DIR=...` and `WORKDIR $SRC_DIR` twice?

Comment: @mae I think so: (1) `ENV SRC_DIR` defines a `docker build`+`docker run` environment variable, and `WORKDIR $SRC_DIR` amounts to running `mkdir -p "$SRC_DIR" && cd "$SRC_DIR"` so that, for example, we can just use a relative path `./bin/grafana-server` in the end, without the need for spawning a shell or so.
(2) next, it happens the Dockerfile relies on the feature of multi-stage-build, so that the `ENV` is lost after the `FROM scratch` command; Regarding the last `WORKDIR $SRC_DIR`, I'm not 100% sure it is necessary in practice, but it has no drawback at all (and increases a bit readability)